# Count of different ways to express N as the sum of given numbers

Tags: dynamic-programming, counting, mathematical-programming

I'm working on a case and I need some help :)

I need to find number of ways and solutions itself to express N as the sum of given numbers.

So, Sum (N) = 600 and the numbers from which I need to get the sum are: 50, 75, 100, 150, 200, 250.

I want to find all different ways (number of ways and solutions) to express 600 as the sum of these given numbers, order does not matter.

Thank you all in advance,

David

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: Do you need to solve the general problem or just that specific instance?
If it's the latter then there are only 32 subsets of $S=\{50, 100, 150, 200, 250\}$ (you can immediately drop $75$ since $600$ and all other values are multiples of $10$, but $75$ is not) and you could just use a brute-force solution. However the sum of the integers in $S$ is $750$, so you might equivalently find the number of ways to remove a set $X$ of total sum $150$ from $S$. A quick inspection of $S$ shows that you either need to select $X=\{150\}$ or $X=\{50, 100\}$. Therefore the number you are looking for is $2$.

Comment: I need to solve specific case, I have given numbers (sizes), which will create final mold/shape for manufacturing final products (with given sizes).  
e.g. with one mold of 50-50-250-250 I can manufacture 2 size of final product, 2 line with 50 millimeters and 2 line with 250 millimeters wide. 
So, I need every different combination on mold that will give me 600 millimeters in size. 
e.g. second mold could be 75-75-200-250 and so on. 
Hope I explained it well.

Comment: So you're allowed to use the same number more than once?

Comment: yes, exactly :)

Comment: This is the change making problem. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/15521/705

Comment: Thanks, I will try to figure it out